# How do I change the Build number format parameter while queuing a build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Online for Source Control and Build processes. I created a new build definition using the TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml. When Queuing a new build from within VS I have the chance to change some parameters, but I can't change the `Build number format`. What determines what shows up on that parameter list and how can I make sure the `Build number format` appears there?

[image]

Comment: The build number increments automatically. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MrHinsh i'm trying to specify the `Build number format` while queuing a new build, but I don't get that Parameter in the list. Instead I have to change the Build Definition, save it, and then queue it.

Comment: Why do you want to change the build number format when queuing a build?

Comment: This build is for UAT and we want the product owner (they are technical) to drive the actual build number based on our release cycle. The build run a pre-build script which assigns the build number format to all the AssemblyInfo.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the property you have to edit the template, expand the arguments, search for Metadata and click on the ellipse towards the right of the row. Find the property you want, in my case it is BuildNumberFormat and change the `View this parameter when:` `Always show the parameter`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to investigate modifying the build template to:
1) Take a custom input value, which I believe you can change on each invocation of the build; and
2) Finding the appropriate step to interrogate the existing Build Number and modify it based on this input.

This should get you started: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx

Alternatively, you could remove the Build Number Activity in its entirety and substitute your own – but I don’t think these measures are warranted in this case.  This would get you started down that trail:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbar/archive/2010/01/21/generating-custom-build-number-in-tfs-build-2010.aspx

HTH –

jlo